# Error when using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to make tensorflow dataset using tensorflow from_generator, I am quite sure that I have made a python generator that work perfectly fine, but when I tried to pass it to from_generator I always got an error. this is the piece of code that I use to create the dataset

```
def dataset_generator(X, Y):
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        img = X[idx, :, :, :]
        labels = Y[idx, :]
        yield img, labels

import tensorflow as tf
ds_generator = dataset_generator(X_data, Y_data)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ds_generator, output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 720, 720, 3], dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 30], dtype=tf.float16)))
```

but when I run it, it always produce error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-af75191f4a28> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 ds_generator = dataset_generator(X_data, Y_data)
----> 3 ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ds_generator, output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 720, 720, 3], dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 30], dtype=tf.float16)))

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args, output_signature)

TypeError: `generator` must be callable.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the problem with your gen function is that you have to pass it as such via the args command, not as function as such

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Gen Function
def dataset_generator(X, Y):
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        img = X[idx, :, :, :]
        labels = Y[idx, :]
        yield img, labels

# Created random data for testing
X_data = np.random.randn(100, 720, 720, 3).astype(np.float32)
Y_data = tf.one_hot(np.random.randint(0, 30, (100, )), 30)

# Testing function
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    dataset_generator,
    args=(X_data, Y_data), 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.uint8)
)

# Get output
next(iter(ds.batch(10).take(1)))
```

Comment: It works! thank you, but does it mean that every time I need to call from_generator, I must pass my generator argument via args?

Comment: yes, you have to pass it as a callable, unless u do this without the args and run all of it via just no arg function

Comment: [be carefull:](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) : DEPRECATED: (output_shapes, output_types). use ==>  `output_signature=(  tf.TensorSpec(shape=( 720, 720, 3), dtype=tf.float32),  tf.TensorSpec(shape=(30,), type=tf.uint8)) `